# Verilator - explanation of VerilatedVcdC->dump()

Tags: verilator

I am reading a wonderful Verilator [tutorial](https://zipcpu.com/tutorial/) and in these [slides](https://zipcpu.com/tutorial/lsn-02-regs.pdf) *(page 25)* author uses a library call:

```
tfp->dump(tickcount * 10 - 2);
```

I know that `tfp` is a pointer to a Verilator library object `VerilatedVcdC` and therefore this call is actually:

```
VerilatedVcdC->dump(tickcount * 10 - 2);
```

But what does this call actually do? Description in the header file `/usr/share/verilator/include/verilated_vcd_c.h` is a bit short. It only says this:

```
/// Write one cycle of dump data
```

> **A bit of confusion here:**
>
> Does this means CPU cycle or OS cycle? I programatically
> already found out [here](https://superuser.com/questions/101183/what-is-a-cpu-tick#answer-1646886) that on my Linux Debian OS cycle is 10
> ms. I assume from now on that Verilator authors meant CPU cycle
> because gtkwave in the end will show units of nano seconds (keep reading)!

So `VerilatedVcdC->dump(x)` should theoretically write/dump `x` CPU cycles *(entire period and not ½ period)* of data in the dump file `tfp`.

But author for some reason multiplies this by 10 and substracts 2. His comment than says:

```
//dump 2ns before the tick
```

At first I could not belive this because when `tickcount = 1`, then we get:

```
VerilatedVcdC->dump(8);
```

And therefore we should dump 8 CPU cycles...

For some reason I am wrong and this is confirmed if I upload the dumped file inside the `gtkwave` and check the wave pattern.

[image]

Trully, 2ns of data are dumped at the beginning into the dump file. How is this possible?

---

Is it possible that `x` in `VerilatedVcdC->dump(x)` is actually an **absolute** value of the OS tick counter and not some relative time?

Comment: This appears to change depending on C++/SystemC framework and Verilator version.  It appears that the count (delta) is the 'precision' of a `timescale 1ns/10ps` type statement.  There are also SystemC functions to set these values.  The default seems to be 1ps.  Depending on the verilog processed, the 'delta' will change meaning of the time step.   However, it is always a simulation time and nothing to do with the hosting PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm just beginning with verilator also. i believe x represents the delay in your circuit you created with verilog. its called 'delta' in some books. it should not be related to anything running on your machine specifically.for tickcount = 1, the call dumps data at value (1 * 10 - 2) which is delta = 8. the next count is (2 * 10 - 2) which is delta = 18 so on and so forth. here's a link to the tutorial i'm following: https://www.itsembedded.com/dhd/verilator_1/ .in short, tickcount is not related to your machine, its the simulation 'time'

Comment: I also found the solution here: https://github.com/verilator/verilator/issues/2924

Answer (score 1):

I got tripped at that same point in ZipCPU's tutorial, and it took me a while to figure out a very simple solution: the key is that the argument to `VerilatedVcdC->dump()` is not a "delay", but "a moment in time".

In other words, it's the simulation time point at which you dump -- in practice, if (as in the tutorial) you dump following every clock tick and 'eval()', just keep incrementing the argument by one. See explanation in Verilator's [issue 2924](https://github.com/verilator/verilator/issues/2924), as mentioned by @71GA in an earlier comment.